# Are items converted to Bucket items still accessible via the original path?

Tags: buckets

A client of mine uses Sitecore and has an item with thousands of children which can't be restructured due to integration. They have queried about the use of buckets which I have limited knowledge.

I was wondering whether the items are still accessible in code using the items' original path or if it is lost once it becomes a bucketed item?

I suspect not but can't find anything conclusive online.

Comment: How are your items currently structured? In a flat structure directly under the parent folder or some sort of other yy/mm structure (or something else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not, but there are two ways that I can think of to get around it:

1. Create aliases for each item to their original URL
2. Create a custom `httpRequestBegin` pipeline processor, similar to `ItemResolver`, that locates the real item by performing an index search

Answer (score 1):

If you will make bucketable items then path will be changed like - http://abc/blog/2018/02/01/blogname.
In bucket.config there is setting

```
<setting name="BucketConfiguration.BucketFolderPath"
> value="yyyy\/MM\/dd"/>
```

from which you can control folder structure in sitecore.

You need to create **custom Item Resolver** and **Custom Link Provider** to access item from original path.

Use this url http://www.codeflood.net/blog/2013/07/18/item-buckets-and-urls/ for custom item resolver and custom link provider.